# Apache Hide Sub folder after Redirect

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a domain that redirects to a sub folder like so `www.domain.com/blog`

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
```

However I would like to hide the `/blog` I have reviewed the Apache documentation but I am unsure how to complete this. The reason why I need this is because I have three domains that point to the same IP address that have different sub folders for the different domains.

In addition if I have the other domains would I use the following:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain2.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog2 [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?domain3.com$
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ blog3 [L]
```

Would this be a valid .htaccess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're making this too complicated. Set up apache with one VirtualHost section for each site and each VirtualHost will have it's own DocumentRoot folder that points to the appropriate blog folder.